# Why the using optimized parameters (MSE is the minimize objective) in the XGBRegressor gives me different RMSE than the optimized RMSE?

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, gpyopt

I am dealing with a regressor problem. I am at the step to tune the parameters of XGBRegressor model so I use the library GPyOpt to get the optimized parameters. The functions returns an array of 5 elements and the minimized MSE which is 1813. Then I try to input the optimized parameters in the model then the MSE for the model returns 2810. I wonder why that happened?

I am really familiar with the library GPyOpt. There isnt a lot of information about this problem I am facing so I wonder it is because of my careless mistake or there is something that I dont understand?

```
import GPyOpt
from GPyOpt.methods import BayesianOptimization
def cv_score(parameters):
    parameters = parameters[0]
    score = cross_val_score(
                XGBRegressor(learning_rate=parameters[0],
                              gamma=int(parameters[1]),
                              max_depth=int(parameters[2]),
                              n_estimators=int(parameters[3]),
                              min_child_weight = parameters[4]), 
                x_train, y_train, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error').mean()
    score = np.array(score)
    return score

bds = [{'name': 'learning_rate', 'type': 'continuous', 'domain': (0, 1)},
        {'name': 'gamma', 'type': 'continuous', 'domain': (0, 5)},
        {'name': 'max_depth', 'type': 'discrete', 'domain': (1, 50)},
        {'name': 'n_estimators', 'type': 'discrete', 'domain': (1, 300)},
        {'name': 'min_child_weight', 'type': 'discrete', 'domain': (1, 10)}]


optimizer = BayesianOptimization(f=cv_score, domain=bds,
                                 model_type='GP',
                                 acquisition_type ='EI',
                                 acquisition_jitter = 0.05,
                                 exact_feval=True, 
                                 maximize=True)
optimizer.run_optimization(max_iter=20)
```

```
optimizer.x_opt
```

> > > array([  0.56133897,   2.697656  ,  50.        , 300.        ,
> > >               10.        ])

```
xgb_final_param = {'learning_rate': 0.56133897, 'gamma': 2.697656, 'max_depth': 50, 'n_estimators': 300, 'min_child_weight': 10}
xgb_final = SklearnExtra(clf = XGBRegressor(), seed = Seed, params = xgb_final_param)
xgb_final.fit(x_train, y_train)
evaluate(xgb_final, x_test, y_test) #evaluate returns MSE
```

I expect the MSE to be roughly around 1813 but I got 2810. So I wonder why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discrete variables in gpyopt aren't specified by their min/max, but by their whole value list instead. Why? Because you may have discontinuity, that is your variable might be only taking values `(1, 3, 8)`. See an example of it [here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/SheffieldML/GPyOpt/blob/master/manual/GPyOpt_mixed_domain.ipynb).

So in your example the way to properly specify the the domain for these is to generate a list of all possible values:

```
{'name': 'max_depth', 'type': 'discrete', 'domain': list(range(1, 51))}
```

Likewise for other discrete variables. Note that for continuous your code is fine - they are specified by their range.